# Get input values from dynamically created edit text boxes in listview

Tags: android, arrays, button, android-edittext, clicklistener

I have a listview that contain several EditTexts created dynamically according to the number of elements in listview.The items in listview are filled by data from server. With each edit text, there is a 'add' button in each row in that same listview. What i want is ,when the user inputs some number in those edit text boxes and click on 'add' button, the numbers input should be stored in some array in the order of clicking(first input in first position of array).The data is for future use to show input numbers in a seperate listview. In my code,when i input some number in edit text box and click 'add' only the first input works.In next clicks,nothing works(toast is shown here)..pls help..You may edit the code.Thanks in advance.(what i want is to store all those inputs, its user's choice to input in selected boxes only)

```
public void Addcart(View v)
{

try{    final EditText editnum= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext); 

View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        if(v.getId()==R.id.addbutton)
        { //  switch (v.getId()){
      //  case R.id.addbutton:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Input: " + editnum.getText().toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           //   break;
        }
    }
};

findViewById(R.id.addbutton).setOnClickListener(handler);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Android Edit Text Example", e.toString());
```

}

Comment: onClick for addbutton is specified in xml file..so when ever add button is clicked,the addcart() is to be executed

Comment: you have to this inside your getView method of the list adapter individually for each button and edit text before adding to the parent or returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have created class which extends BaseAdapter. which does work of rendering view of list inside getView() method. 
So, you can easily get the position of that list row (getView(int ) argument is position your rendering) and also inside it you can create and your edittext dynamically also add button setting listeners.

now you can get position of row your clicking by using onItemclickListener() for that list returns the position of row hit by user,

so in on Addbutton click you can create Vector and insert that entered element in vector at specified index by using it's method.

so, next time you render new list you can use this vector as list to pass as data of numbers.

hope explanation works for you ..

Comment: I don't use a class that extends BaseAdapter..Please mention how i can show a toast message that displays input number when a user inputs number in any(or all) of the edit text box and press 'add button'

Comment: can you please provide the code how your r adding buttons to list and handling listeners on them ..

Comment: In above code your trying to read same edittext every time method calls but it's id is same and as you mention you added edittext dynamically so, wht your writing... provde code ..